# fileURI and filePath : phonegap plugin capture and camera

Tags: ios, xcode4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using capture plugin for video recording
and using camera plugin for the images (from gallery and camera)

But as response from both I am getting different format result.

*As in Video Case(Capture) I am getting image path as fullPath*
`/private/var/mobile/Applications/3736F94E-F57B-4537-A352-1B746B1D67FF/tmp/capture/capturedvideo.MOV`
*and in Image Case(Camera) I am getting the fileURI*
`file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/3736F94E-F57B-4537-A352-1B746B1D67FF/tmp/photo_002.jpg`

Can anybody tell me the reason for that? Why doesn't it return the same format for both?

As I am using phonegap with iOS
so for converting the image/video into NSData I have to use initWithContentsOfURL, initWithContentsOfFile respectively.

**Amit Batta**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/91a75d4b18673f23/8287cb022f353d42#8287cb022f353d42